# Incompatibility of biblatex and tex4ht when using defernumbers

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, tex4ht, subdividing

There seems to be a [known incompatibility](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.tex4ht/69) between `biblatex` and `tex4ht` when using `defernumbers=true`.
I have one large `.bib` file. In the document I want to group the references into different categories. When using numerical labels, this requires `defernumbers=true` to obtain consecutive numbering.

Everything works fine, apart from that `htlatex` chokes on this option with the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
```

Forcing the run to continue for the example below, I obtain a usable .html, but there is a erroneous `span` tag right at the beginning:

```
<span 
class="cmr-10">01 12</span>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This example illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib} 
@article{Smith42,
    AUTHOR = {Smith}, 
    TITLE = {Some Title}, 
    JOURNAL = {Some Journal},
    YEAR = {1942},
}
@article{Aronson12,
    AUTHOR = {Aronson}, 
    TITLE = {Some Title}, 
    JOURNAL = {Some Journal},
    YEAR = {1912},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex} 
% The following instead of the previous line works with tex4ht, but the numbering is not as desired.
%\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex} 

\bibliography{sample.bib} 

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{group1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{group2}
\addtocategory{group1}{Smith42}
\addtocategory{group2}{Aronson12,Smith42}

\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[category=group1]
\printbibliography[category=group2]
\end{document}
```

Note that the problem doesn't occur without the option `defernumbers=true`. I am using an up-to-date TL 2011 distribution, i.e., a `biblatex.sty` version 1.7 dated 2011/11/13 19:09:07 and `biblatex.4ht` dated 2011-09-18-16:07.

Is there a workaround for this that doesn't require editing the `.bib` file?

Comment: Apparently the above example works fine nowadays. I just tested it in Arch Linux with `htlatex` from `texlive-core`  version `2022.63035-1` and the current `biber` from the community repo. However, the automatic generation of `sample.bib` only worked for me after removing `\usepackage{filecontents}` and changing `\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}` into `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this will help exactly with the problem above - but I'll try to jot down my debugging steps. I was using a customized bibliography sorting in `biblatex`, which then requires `biber` - and, all being good in the PDF - as soon as I wanted to build this using `htlatex`, `biber`, `htlatex` - I got the above error (only when the `.aux` file is present)..

So first I get something like:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.29 ...backref{1}{myfirstcite}{0}{4}{4}
```

I search with `grep` through files to find this ...`backref{1}{myfirstcite}` - and it turns out it is in the `.aux` file; contents around that line look like this:

```
...
\select@language{american}
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{american}}
\@writefile{lof}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{american}}
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{american}}
\abx@aux@backref{1}{myfirstcite}{0}{4}{4}
\abx@aux@page{1}{4}
...
```

So I go back, run `htlatex` again - and now when it stops at error, I press '`I`' in the shell to insert, and then just type `\show` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (<kbd>ENTER</kbd> maybe twice) - this spits an additional error message:

```
?
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\abx@aux@backref ...{#2}}{#4}}\blx@addpagesum {#1}
                                                  {#5}
l.29 ...backref{1}{myfirstcite}{0}{4}{4}
```

Ok, so by now, I'm pretty sure `tex4ht` doesn't like `\abx@aux@backref`.

So, I search first for the macro `\abx@aux@page` - and it turns out it is present in `biblatex.4ht` file (from `tex4ht`); a snippet looks like:

```
%biblatex.4ht
%
% ...
  \def\abx@aux@page#1#2{\blx@addpagesum{#1}{#2}}%
  \def\abx@aux@fnpage#1#2{\blx@addpagesum{#1}{#2}}}
% ...
```

... but it also appears in `biblatex.sty` (from `biblatex`).

Then I search for `\abx@aux@backref` - and, as suspected - this one is defined in `biblatex.sty`, but *not* in `biblatex.4ht`; which is probably the reason why it crashes.

Now, `\abx@aux@backref` contains an `@`, meaning I'd have to define it in between `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` - somewhere in the preamble after both `biblatex` and `tex4ht` are loaded. However, often times in similar cases I just do `\let\abx@aux@backref\relax` - but, that will not work here, because the original command always has five arguments.

So, after another search through `biblatex.sty`, I find: "`\protected\def\blx@aux@backref#1#2#3#4#5{...`" - and while that is not the same command, it is certainly to related to something `@aux@backref` ... So, in the end I put this in my preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\abx@aux@backref#1#2#3#4#5{}
\makeatother
```

... and now the `htlatex`, `biber`, `htlatex` combo seems to pass for me?!

Well, not sure how right I am about all this - but certainly hope it helps,
Cheers!

Comment: This is perfect! Everything works now that I have that mysterious `blx@aux@backref` stuff in my preamble. Surely the biblatex people or the tex4ht people can do something about this, since it is fixable.

Comment: In my example the `htlatex` run fails with `l.9 \abx@aux@number{0}{Smith42}{0}{1}` (at least for me). If I just blank out `\abx@aux@number` like you did with `\abx@aux@backref`, then `htlatex` indeed passes. However, the html output does not reflect the option `defernumbers=true` (i.e., the numbering is the standard one).

Answer (score 1):

The biblatex.4ht which you use is incompatible with biblatex 1.7. You can use http://von-wachter.de/dateien/for-biblatex-1-6/biblatex.4ht with http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/biblatex-1.6/.

Comment: Well, I think that I had tried this already before I posted my question here. Anyhow, I gave your suggestion a try and downgraded to `biblatex-1.6` using the above `biblatex.4ht`. For my MWE it behaves exactly the same, i.e., it gives the same error and the same defective `html` output.