# Why does biblatex produce `defcounter` lines in .toc?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

**Questions**

*With `biblatex` loaded,* why does the `.toc` have the line

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
```

immediately preceding each and every ordinary `\contentsline` line?

And how can it be prevented without unwanted side-effects?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chap}
\kant[1]
\section{Test}
\kant[1]
\subsection{Test}
\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

The `.toc` produced is:

```
\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse{pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{i}{section*.1}% 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chap}{1}{chapter.1}% 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Test}{1}{section.1.1}% 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{1}{section*.2}%
```

And of course the `.aux` is:

```
\relax 
\abx@aux@refcontext{nty/global//global/global}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chap}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{lof}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Test}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}Test}{1}\protected@file@percent }
```

*Without `biblatex` loaded,* the same source produces the straightforward `.toc`:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{i}% 
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chap}{1}% 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Test}{1}% 
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{1}%
```

**Notes:** The very same thing happens with document class `book` as for `memoir`. The same thing happens if option `[backend=bibtex]` is used for `biblatex` instead of the default `biber`.

**Origin of the question:**

The intervening `\defcounter...` lines are troublesome when both a short and a detailed TOC are produced, as in the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513455/13492 to
[memoir + biblatex + 2 TOCs error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513429/memoir-biblatex-2-tocs-error).

**Possibly Rrelated:** https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53972/13492

Comment: I think this has to be the wrong way to go about this. Biblatex isn't the only package which writes additional stuff to the `.toc`. The code you're trying to use looks inherently fragile to me. All kinds of things will screw it up. (If you think Biblatex is bad, you should see what babel does to my `.toc`s. At least Biblatex only adds its thing once per entry. There are also situations in which you might want to write additional stuff to the `.toc` without needing to worry about this.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

`biblatex` v3.17 uses a new approach to deal with the required "initialisation" in auxiliary files that means that `biblatex` no longer writes lines of its own to those files.

See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1116 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1166 as well as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/408 for some background.

This should keep aux files much more predictable when `biblatex` is involved.

With v3.17 and above the `.toc` file will look as desired

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{i}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chap}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Test}{1}{}%
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{1}{}%
```

---

### Old answer

**tl;dr**

`biblatex` produces the `\defcounter{refsection}` lines in the `.toc` to be able to correctly pick up `refsection` membership for citations in chapter/section/... headings in the the ToC. The relevant patch to `\addtocontents` can be removed without negative effects if you (i) don't use `refsection`s or (ii) don't cite in chapter/section/... headings.

---

I'll first explain a way to undo `biblatex`'s patch to `\addtocontents` that adds this `\defcounter` command and we can then look at an example that shows why this patch is necessary.

`biblatex` patches `\addtocontents` in an `\AtEndPreamble` hook, so if we want to undo the patch one possibility is to hook into `\AtEndPreamble` before `biblatex` to save the original definition of `\addtocontents` and then again after `biblatex` has done its thing to restore the definition.

Written compactly this might look like

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\let\murray@saved@addtocontents\addtocontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\AtEndPreamble{\let\addtocontents\murray@saved@addtocontents}
\makeatother
```

Then following MWE demonstrates the need for the patch

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\let\murray@saved@addtocontents\addtocontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\AtEndPreamble{\let\addtocontents\murray@saved@addtocontents}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\begin{refsection}
\chapter{Chap}
\kant[1] \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
\section{Test \autocite{sigfridsson}}
\kant[1] 
\subsection{Test}
\kant[1]
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\chapter{Chap}
\kant[1] \autocite{geer,sigfridsson}
\section{Test \autocite{sigfridsson}}
\kant[1] 
\subsection{Test}
\kant[1]
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

%\autocite{geer,nussbaum,sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: undefined citations in ToC]

The patch becomes important if your document contains different `refsection`s. `refsection`s are kept completely separated from each other and each contain their own citations and bibliography. When you then cite an entry in chapter/section/... title and that title goes to the ToC, the citation is not in the original `refsection` any more (the ToC need not be printed in the same `refsection` as the original citation: indeed this will rarely be the case in per-chapter `refsection`s) and `biblatex` does not know where the citation belongs. In this example that means that `biblatex` simply gives up.

If you uncomment the `\autocite{geer,nussbaum,sigfridsson}` at the end, you see another bad effect. The citation number in the ToC is "[3]", but in the section headings the numbers are "[1]" and "[2]".

[image: Citations are [3] in ToC.]

The effect might be slightly less pronounced in other set-ups, but whenever your document contains several `refsection`s and you cite something in a chapter/section/... heading, the patch is necessary to make sure the citations come out correctly in the ToC.

---

`biblatex` is not the only package that inserts context information into the `.toc` file.

Take the following `babel` example (also alluded to by [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513550/why-does-biblatex-produce-defcounter-lines-in-toc#comment1298754_513550))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[british,dutch,naustrian,ngerman]{babel}

\def\month{1}% we need january where German German and Austrian German differ
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{otherlanguage}{british}
\section{\protect\today}
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{\protect\today}

\begin{otherlanguage}{naustrian}
\section{\protect\textcolor{red}{\protect\today}}
\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{otherlanguage}{dutch}
\section{\protect\today}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: A ToC with date headings in different languages.]

To be able to correctly identify the language and with it the expected date format in each heading, `babel` adds language information to the `.toc`

```
\babel@toc {ngerman}{}
\babel@toc {british}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\today }{1}% 
\babel@toc {ngerman}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}\today }{1}% 
\babel@toc {naustrian}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}\textcolor {red}{\today }}{1}% 
\babel@toc {ngerman}{}
\babel@toc {dutch}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}\today }{1}% 
\babel@toc {ngerman}{}
```

`polyglossia` does the same, but the `.toc` looks even more complex (tested with the upcoming `polyglossia` version v1.45, because earlier versions would not do enough here, see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/205).

```
\selectlanguage *{german}
\bgroup 
\selectlanguage *{english}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\today }{1}% 
\egroup 
\selectlanguage *{german}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}\today }{1}% 
\bgroup 
\selectlanguage *[variant=austrian]{german}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}\textcolor {red}{\today }}{1}% 
\egroup 
\selectlanguage *{german}
\bgroup 
\selectlanguage *{dutch}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}\today }{1}% 
\egroup 
\selectlanguage *{german}
```

So you can't really rely on your `.toc` file to contain only `\contentsline` lines with nothing in between.

---

It gets even worse for your murderer from [memoir + biblatex + 2 TOCs error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513429/35864). Compare the `.toc` of

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chap}
\kant[1]
\section{Test}
\kant[1] 
\subsection{Test}
\kant[1]

\chapter{Chap}
\kant[1]
\section{Test}
\kant[1] 
\subsection{Test}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

without `hyperref`

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{i}% 
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chap}{1}% 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Test}{1}% 
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{1}% 
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Chap}{3}% 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Test}{3}% 
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{3}%
```

to the `.toc` with `hyperref`

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{i}{section*.1}% 
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chap}{1}{chapter.1}% 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Test}{1}{section.1.1}% 
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{1}{section*.2}% 
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Chap}{3}{chapter.2}% 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Test}{3}{section.2.1}% 
\contentsline {subsection}{Test}{3}{section*.3}%
```

The number of arguments to `\contentsline` changes! This means you can't even be sure how many arguments to gobble if you don't know if `hyperref` is loaded or not.

Comment: Then what is your solution to the OPs original problem of making two tocs with xref entries (aka first item is a hyperref ref to the other), while running on the same toc file. I agree that the murderer approach is flawed, but for a single document where you know what you are using, that is not a big problem. The idea is also to now redefine too much or hyperref anchor placement probbly comes back to bit you. Probably "easiest" to insert an if construction around the two toc entries, if one can get an unmatched if to go into the toc

Comment: @daleif The trouble is that 'a single document where you know what you are using' is a rare commodity. Even if you know what you're using now, do you know if anything you're using will not start writing to the `.toc` following some update? Or write something different to the `.toc`? This isn't to deny the ingenuity of your solution or to claim I have a better idea. :(