# biblatex confounds AMS's solution for eliminating TOC entries

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning, amsart

[The AMS suggests to](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238) remove a TOC entry from an `amsart` document by suppressing the entry just before it is to be added to the TOC.

Their solution works without the `biblatex` package loaded. However, when I load the `biblatex` package, it fails, and that TOC entry is still printed even with the skip command. Please see the below MWE demonstrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
% \usepackage{biblatex} %uncomment to see difference
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
\section{First}
\end{document}
```

Notice that it is not necessary to *use* `biber` in the compilation to demonstrate the issue. Using `pdflatex` on the document alone shows the difference.

Comment: If you load `biblatex` you need to gobble more in the `.toc` file, since `biblatex` writes some commands to that file. `\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[8]{}` works.

Comment: *Very* related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513550/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513429/35864

Comment: @moewe, that led me to the solution. Gobbling more of the TOC line did exactly what I needed. Would you like to write up the answer so that I can credit you for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed at length in [Why does biblatex produce `defcounter` lines in .toc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513550/35864), `biblatex` adds additional content to the `.toc` file. So when you load it you get

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{First}}{1}%
```

instead of just

```
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{First}}{1}%
```

Hence, if you want to gobble the line, you need to gobble more.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{biblatex} %uncomment to see difference
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[8]{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
\section{First}
\end{document}
```

If you load `hyperref` you need to gobble even more, because the argument structure changes.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[9]{}
```